# Google "Featured Snippet" on Git Question shows a Downvoted/Deleted Answer

Tags: discussion, google, seo

So, I came across a rather odd thing this morning. Curious to know exactly *what is the difference between a branch and a tag in Git*, I plugged into my trusty Google search. And, lo and behold, the [following (incorrect) result](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+difference+between+branch+and+tag&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab) popped up (see screenshot).

I, being ever curious, visited [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017508/what-is-the-difference-between-tag-and-branch-with-git) and was pleased to see that there were some correct answers, and a link to a duplicate question. But the problem is, the actual answer that is quoted was **misleading** (first sentence) and **deleted**. Why is Stack Overflow feeding incorrect information to the Google?

Screenshot:

[image: image of google search]

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is feeding anything wrong. From the "About this result" link: "**How can I mark my page as a featured snippet?**
You can't. Google programmatically determines that a page contains a likely answer to the user's question, and displays the result as a featured snippet." You may want to click the "Feedback" link...

Comment: Stack Overflow is feeding correct information to Google. **It is Google that fails to use it**.

Comment: Also see [Google "answering" my search with link to SE, but not showing the top answer(s)](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/233845) over on Uber Meta. You can let Google know that the snippet was not useful by using the Feedback link, please do so.

Comment: Actually, that answer is **not deleted**. It is merely downvoted, it has a score of -3.